# Get latest messages from last known mail Id - Mailcore

Tags: ios, swift, email, mailcore2

Is it possible to get messages based on the last known Email UID. I am able to fetch emails using "fetchMessagesByNumberOperation" method. But somehow i need to implement a way to fetch newest emails from the last known email id.

> Let say i have fetched x latest emails. And after 5 minutes i
>   got three more emails. Now i want to fetch the latest emails from the
>   last saved UID.

**`Is it possible to do?`**

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to do?

Yes it is.

There is a method named `fetchMessagesByUIDOperation` for this.
Here is my code in Kotlin, you can achieve same with swift

```
imapSession().fetchMessagesByUIDOperation(folder, flags,
            IndexSet.indexSetWithRange(Range(lastMessageUID, Range.RangeMax)))
```